# How to make some column's content in the datagrid to be hyperlink?

Tags: wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid

I am wondering if it is an easy task. I need to have some of the text inside the datagrid to be hyperlinks. I generated content with XMLDataProvider. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

My DataGrid looks below. I am working with WPF toolkit:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MainGrid" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeight="20" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/ServicesTiles/Servers}"
                              HeadersVisibility="None" Margin="10,15,0,0" 
                              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{x:Null}" 
                              BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                              VerticalGridLinesBrush="{x:Null}" 
                              Background="{x:Null}"
                              RowBackground="{x:Null}"
                              CellStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridCellStyle1}" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}" Foreground="#FF6E6E6E" MinWidth="160" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@Status}" Foreground="#FF6E6E6E" MinWidth="270"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name2}" Foreground="#FF6E6E6E" MinWidth="220"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@Status2}" Foreground="#FF6E6E6E" MinWidth="220"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the `Command` on the `Hyperlink`. If you want to call back into the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` you will need to make use of `FindAncestor` and search for type `DataGrid`.

```
        <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Hyperlink Command="{Binding DoStuff}"/>
                    </TextBlock >
                </DataTemplate >
            </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I have the same issue as I desribed for HCL above. I was wondering how I can restyle DataGridTextColumn with your technique in the datagrid code I added in the my question. Thank you again.

Comment: Don't forget the FindAncestor part if you want to call back into the DataContext. I missed that and spent hours trying to figure out why it didn't work, i.e. `<Hyperlink Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=views:ComponentsGrid}, Path=DataContext.ViewComponentXmlCommand}">` from the code above.

Answer (score 4):

The following DataGridColumn should do what you want (I have not tested, make a comment, if it does not work)

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock >
                <Hyperlink>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourProperty}" />                                                                                    
                </Hyperlink>                                    
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                        
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**Edit**
as requested, here my proposition how to insert. Let me know if it works...

```
<DataGrid.Columns> 
 <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}" Foreground="#FF6E6E6E" MinWidth="160" /> 
 <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@Status}" Foreground="#FF6E6E6E" MinWidth="270"/> 
 <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name2}" Foreground="#FF6E6E6E" MinWidth="220"/> 
 <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=@Status2}" Foreground="#FF6E6E6E" MinWidth="220"/> 
 <DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock >
                <Hyperlink>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name2}" />                                                                                    
                </Hyperlink>                                    
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                        
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>

</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: I cannot apply this DataTemplate in my case. I added the datagrid code in the my question. Please look. I am wondering where I can set DataGridTemplateColumn style in my case. Thank you again.

Comment: For some reason 'DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate' property is not recognized. I cannot add it. I amm getting error. I am wondering what can be wrong?

Comment: @vladc77: What is the namespace you have given for the toolkit? In your example I don't see any.

Comment: It worked. I found out what I was doing wrong. Thank you for your help.